# How to select N columns from a PowerBI table?

Tags: excel, select, powerbi

I have the following table with three columns A, B, and C on PowerBI, from which I want to select columns A and B to create a new table.

And looking from the equivalent in Pandas to:

```
table_2 = table1[["A","B"]]
```

or from SQL:

```
SELECT A,B FROM table1;
```

But I'm not finding the equivalent function on Power BI; the [SELECTCOLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectcolumns-function-dax) function is used to create a new column as stated in the docs:

> Adds calculated columns to the given table or table expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SELECTCOLUMNS` function works fine for this. It allows you to create more complex calculated columns, but you can simply use the column itself as the calculation definition.

This should do the trick:

```
SELECTCOLUMNS(table1, "A", table1[A], "B", table1[B])
```

Comment: Awesome, does this points to table1 or creates a copy of the columns?

Comment: This creates a new table.

Comment: I have created a new table which appears in the main windows, but when I go to **edit queries** the new table is now there.

Comment: Right. Any DAX calculated tables don't flow back to the query editor. If you need it there, then create the new table in the query editor instead. It's even easier there.