# How can I create a new table in Power BI from three columns of another two table with a filter?

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, new-operator

I have used below DAX & result is ok but pls help me to get same data from two tables

1. SALES
2. RETURNS

both tables have same 3 columns.. & I want to take this data in new table..

Pls help me to get this from two tables into one

---

[How to select N columns from a PowerBI table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54220927/how-to-select-n-columns-from-a-powerbi-table)

answered Oct 6, 2020 at 14:33
Alexis Olson

The SELECTCOLUMNS function allows you to pick specific columns.

For example:

```
New Filtered Table =
Customers = DISTINCT(
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            SALES,
            NOT ( ISBLANK ( SALES[Customer Number] ) ),
            NOT ( ISBLANK ( SALES[Customer Name] ) ),
            NOT ( ISBLANK ( SALES[Customer Location] ) )
        ),
        "Customer Number", SALES[Customer Number],
        "Customer Name", SALES[Customer Name],
        "Customer Location", SALES[Customer Location]
    ))
```

Comment: @AlexisOlson -pls

Comment: Share your sample data in text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the SELECTCOLUMNS() function from your question on both tables and then combine the result with the UNION() function.

```
Result = 
UNION (
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( SALES, ... ),
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( RETURNS, ...)
)
```